# (proof explanation) Let G be a connected graph with p > 3 points. Then ω(G) = q if and only if G has no triangles

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

To prove the necessity, let ω(G) = q s.t. q is number of edges and assume that G has a triangle.
Then let G1 be a maximal triangle-free spanning subgraph of G. By the
preceding paragraph. ω(G1) = q1 = |X(G1)|. *I did not include sufficiency proof since I only need help on necessity part*

Suppose that G1 = Ω(F). where F is a family of subsets of some set S with cardinality q1. Let x be a line of G not in G, and consider G2 = G1 + x. Since G1 is maximal triangle-free. G1 must have some triangle, say u1u2u3 where x = u1u3. Denote by
S1 ,S2, S3 the subsets of S corresponding to u1,u2 , u3. Now if u2 is adjacent
to only u1 and u3 in G2, replace S2 by a singleton chosen from S1 and S2, and
add that element to S3. Otherwise, replace S3 by the union of S3 and any
element in S1∩S2. In either case this gives a family F' of distinct subsets
of S such that G2 = Ω(F). *Thus ω(G2) = q1, while |X(G2)| = q1 + 1.*

**Question: why would ω(G2) = q1? since since G2 has one more edge, shouldn't that make the intersection number of G2 greater than q1? Also when is the intersection number less than the number of edges?**

If G2 is congruent to G, there is nothing to prove. But if G2 ≠ G, then let
|X(G)| - |X(G2)| = q0.
It follows that G is an intersection graph on a set with q1 + q0 elements.
However, q1 + q0 = q - 1. Thus ω(G) < q. completing the proof.

**I do not understand the general strategy of the sufficiency proof**

Comment: What do you mean by $\omega(G)$? Usually, this denotes the clique number of $G$, but if $G$ has no triangles, then you'd always have clique number $2$ (or $1$ if $G$ also has no edges).

Comment: ω(G) is the intersection number of G. wikipedia said that intersection number and clique number is equivalent, but can you tell me how to determine it's value?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the idea of the proof. We assume $G$ is an arbitrary graph with $q$ edges that *does* contain a triangle, and we will show that the intersection number of $G$ is less than $q$. To do this, we need to find an intersection representation of $G$ that uses fewer than $q$ total elements.

We let $G_1$ be a maximal triangle-free spanning subgraph of $G$ with $q_1$ edges, and we let $G_2$ be $G_1$ with one edge added, so $G_2$ has $q_2 = q_1+1$ edges, and contains a triangle. Our proof will proceed in three steps:

1. We start with an intersection representation of $G_1$ that uses $q_1$ elements (this is always possible).
2. We use this to construct an intersection representation of $G_2$ that also uses $q_1$ elements, showing that the intersection number of $G_2$ is *smaller* than the number of edges in $G_2$.
3. Then we use this to construct an intersection representation of $G$ that uses only $q - 1$ elements, showing that the intersection number of $G$ is also smaller than the number of edges in $G$.

---

**Step 1.** We know that $G_1$ has an intersection representation that uses $q_1$ elements for a number of reasons. First of all, you presumably proved it in the half of the proof you skipped. Second, there is always a construction that does this for any graph: assign to each vertex the set of edges incident to it.

In any case, we know that there is a set $S$ with $|S|=q_1$ and a family of sets $S_1, S_2, \dots, S_p \subseteq S$ with the property that $S_i \cap S_j \ne \varnothing$ if and only if there is an edge between vertices $u_i$ and $u_j$ in $G_1$. This is the intersection representation of $G_1$.

---

**Step 2.** We create $G_2$ from $G_1$ by adding an edge that was not already present. It's trivial to modify the representation above to represent $G_2$: just create a new element $z$ and add it to $S_1$ and $S_2$. But then we would be using $q_2 = q_1 + 1$ elements; we would like to do better and use only $q_1$ elements.

Since $G_1$ was maximally triangle-free, in $G_2$ there is a triangle whose vertices we'll call $u_1, u_2, u_3$. One of the edges between these must have been the edge we just added, because $G_1$ didn't have triangles. Let's say that's the edge $(u_1, u_3)$, so $(u_1, u_2)$ and $(u_2, u_3)$ were already edges of $G_1$. The intersection representation of $G_1$ has:

- $S_1 \cap S_2 \ne \varnothing$, since $(u_1, u_2)$ is an edge of $G_1$;
- $S_2 \cap S_3 \ne \varnothing$, since $(u_2, u_3)$ is an edge of $G_1$;
- but $S_1 \cap S_3 = \varnothing$, since $(u_1, u_3)$ is *not* an edge of $G_1$.

Let $s$ be an arbitrary element of $S_1 \cap S_2$. We know that there is no other $S_i$ that contains $s$, because then $u_i$ would be adjacent to $u_1$ and $u_2$ in the graph $G_1$, forming a triangle - and $G_1$ is triangle-free.

So if we modify $S_3$ by changing it to $S_3' = S_3 \cup \{s\}$, we get that $S_1$ and $S_3'$ have a common element. ($S_2$ and $S_3$ already had a common element, and this is still true of $S_2$ and $S_3'$.) But no other new intersections are created. So the result is an intersection representation of a graph that has all the edges of $G_1$, and the edge $(u_1, u_3)$: an intersection representation of $G_2$.

Since we didn't need to add new elements to $S$, this intersection representation has $|S|=q_1$ elements: one fewer than the number of edges in $G_2$. Therefore $G_2$ has intersection number at most $q_1 = q_2 -1$.

---

**Step 3.** Now we construct an intersection representation of $G$ that uses fewer elements than edges in $G$.

This is actually easy. We start from the intersection representation of $G_2$ that uses $q_1 = q_2 - 1$ elements. Then, for every edge $x = (u_i, u_j)$ that's in $G$ but not in $G_2$, we:

- Add a new element $x$ to the set $S$.
- Add $x$ to $S_i$ and to $S_j$, but not to any other sets.

This step makes $S_i \cap S_j \ne \varnothing$ without changing any other intersections. It also costs us the addition of an extra element to $S$. Altogether, if $G_2$ has $q_2$ edges and $G$ has $q$ edges, we needed to add $q - q_2$ extra elements.

But this is okay! We started with $|S| = q_1 = q_2 -1$. Then we added $q - q_2$ elements to $S$, ending up with $|S = (q_2 - 1) + (q - q_2) = q-1$. So we now have an intersection representation of $G$ that uses only $q-1$ elements.

Therefore the intersection number of $G$ is at most $q-1$: fewer than the number of edges in $G$.

Comment: I think I understand now. Although I might still have follow up questions. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why is it valid to modify S3 by adding the common element of S1 and S2 to S3?

Comment: We're creating an intersection representation of $G_2$ by starting with the intersection representation of $G_1$ and modifying it slightly. (We could also have defined an intersection representation of $G_2$ from scratch.)

Comment: so if we define an intersection representation of G2 from scratch then we need to show that since it has a triangle then |S|=q1 is less than the number of edges of G2 by 1...? which is the same as you have demonstrated above right?

Comment: Well, there can be intersection representations of any graph with arbitrarily large $|S|$ (we can just unnecessarily add elements). We'd need to make use of the triangle to define *some* representation of $G_2$ with $q_1$ elements.

Comment: but when defining it from scratch, we need to assure that we don't add any elements not from the elements of G1. how exactly would that happen?

Comment: okay, but why would it be valid to "unnecessarily add elements"?

Comment: An intersection representation is just *any* family of sets $S_1, S_2, \dots, S_p$ that intersects in the right way. I can decide to arbitrarily add a billion elements to $S_1$ and to no other set, and that's still a valid intersection representation of the same graph, since it doesn't change which sets have nontrivial intersection.

Comment: "any family of sets" made it click for me. thank you Misha! :)